# what is the significance of having application server?

Tags: webserver, application-server, infrastructure, multi-tier

In multi-tier infrastructure design, mostly all new web servers are capable enough to process the requests with high computation power. Why do we application servers as a separate tier even if web servers are capable to perform all the operations?
(Consider a scenario where IIS is capable of working as a web server and application server, why that is not the case with JAVA tech, having webserver and application servers different)